# How to display table in html using javascript whn button is cliked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the wa tablle to display in HTML using javascript whenever certain values are entered in a textbox and button is clicked  heres my code

```
   <html>
<head> 
<title> Routes </title>
<link  rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href = "css/rocolours.css" >
<script = "text/javascript">
function somefunction(){
var result = document.getElementById("sub");
var results = result.value;
if(results == "west acres"){
document.getElementById('wa').style.visibility = "visible"

}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<p id ="logo" align ="center">WARHTOG EXPRESS LINEAR</p>
</header>

<ul id ="navbar">
<li> <a href="Home.html">Home</a> </li>
<li> <a href="Specials.html">Specials</a> </li>
<li> <a href="Contactus.html">Contact Us</a> </li>
<li> <a href="Routes.html">Routes</a> </li>
<li> <a href="Products">Products</a> </li>
<li> <a href="Conditions.html">Conditions</a> </li>
<li><a href="Aboutus.html">About Us</a> </li>
</ul>
<div id ="content">
<p id = heading>Here are the various routes our vehicles take and how much each one costs
<br>
</p>
<br>
<form>
Enter depature area/suburb:<br>
<input id ="sub" type="text" name="subs"><br>
<br>
<input type ="button" value = "Search" onclick="somefunction()">
</form>
<table id ="wa" border = "1" width="400" style ="display:none">
<caption><b> West Acres ROUTES</b></caption>
<thead>
<tr><th>  Route</th><th>Fare</th><th>Vehicle number</th></tr>
<tfoot></tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr><td>West Acres to  Sonheuwel</td><td>R10</td><td>T101</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to Nelsville </td><td>R11</td><td>T102</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to Dykrus </td><td>R5</td><td>T103</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to Stonehenge</td><td>R10</td><td>T103</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to CBD</td><td>R20</td><td>T104</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to Kamagugu</td><td>R17</td><td>T105</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to  Sonheuwel central</td><td>R11</td><td>T101</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to  Riverside</td><td>R10</td><td>T106</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to  Pumlanga Ah</td><td>R13</td><td>T101</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to  Vintonia</td><td>R10</td><td>T105</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to  Nelspruit airport</td><td>R20</td><td>T107</td></tr>
<tr><td>Nelspruit airport to CBD</td><td>R25</td><td>T201</td></tr>
<tr><td>Nelspruit airport to Riverside</td><td></td><td>T202</td></tr>
<tr><td> Nelspruit airport to Sonheuwel</td><td>R</td><td>T203</td></tr>
<tr><td> Nelspruit airport to Vintonia</td><td>R</td><td>T203</td></tr>
<tr><td> Nelspruit airport to Nelsville</td><td>R</td><td>T203</td></tr>
<tr><td> Nelspruit airport to Pumlanga</td><td>R</td><td>T203</td></tr>
<tr><td> Nelspruit airport to Stonehenge</td><td>R</td><td>T203</td></tr>
<tr><td> Nelspruit airport to Stonehenge</td><td>R</td><td>T203</td></tr>
</tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'm new to html so I'm not sure what the problem is

Comment: You have not changed display:none of table!

Comment: also first set all td display to none and then add display block to only those rows you want to show

Comment: you changed its visibility and not display property of the table. and also i think you want to display only 'west acres' rows and not all rows of the table. change your logic then if you want that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the `visibility` in JavaScript whereas the `display` is still `none`.
So, Change the `display` to `''`.

```js
function somefunction(){
var result = document.getElementById("sub");
var results = result.value;
if(results == "west acres"){
document.getElementById('wa').style.display='';

}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head> 
<title> Routes </title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<p id ="logo" align ="center">WARHTOG EXPRESS LINEAR</p>
</header>


<div id ="content">
<p id = heading>Here are the various routes our vehicles take and how much each one costs
<br>
</p>
<br>
<form>
Enter depature area/suburb:<br>
<input id ="sub" type="text" name="subs"><br>
<br>
<input type ="button" value = "Search" onclick="somefunction()" />
</form>
<table id ="wa" border = "1" width="400" style ="display:none">
<caption><b> West Acres ROUTES</b></caption>
<thead>
<tr><th>  Route</th><th>Fare</th><th>Vehicle number</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>West Acres to  Sonheuwel</td><td>R10</td><td>T101</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to Nelsville </td><td>R11</td><td>T102</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to Dykrus </td><td>R5</td><td>T103</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to Stonehenge</td><td>R10</td><td>T103</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to CBD</td><td>R20</td><td>T104</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to Kamagugu</td><td>R17</td><td>T105</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to  Sonheuwel central</td><td>R11</td><td>T101</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to  Riverside</td><td>R10</td><td>T106</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to  Pumlanga Ah</td><td>R13</td><td>T101</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to  Vintonia</td><td>R10</td><td>T105</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Acres to  Nelspruit airport</td><td>R20</td><td>T107</td></tr>
<tr><td>Nelspruit airport to CBD</td><td>R25</td><td>T201</td></tr>
<tr><td>Nelspruit airport to Riverside</td><td></td><td>T202</td></tr>
<tr><td> Nelspruit airport to Sonheuwel</td><td>R</td><td>T203</td></tr>
<tr><td> Nelspruit airport to Vintonia</td><td>R</td><td>T203</td></tr>
<tr><td> Nelspruit airport to Nelsville</td><td>R</td><td>T203</td></tr>
<tr><td> Nelspruit airport to Pumlanga</td><td>R</td><td>T203</td></tr>
<tr><td> Nelspruit airport to Stonehenge</td><td>R</td><td>T203</td></tr>
<tr><td> Nelspruit airport to Stonehenge</td><td>R</td><td>T203</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Javadeveloper if it is helpful to you, you can mark it as answer for reference of future visitors

Answer (score 2):

Just add:

```
    document.getElementById('wa').style.display = "block";
```

after the:

```
        document.getElementById('wa').style.visibility = "visible";
```

line.